# How can I list all credentials in dynamodb docker container on local?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using docker image to run dynamodb on local computer. Below is the docker compose file I used to launch the container.

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  dbs:
    image: amazon/dynamodb-local:1.16.0
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
```

Then I use aws dynamodb cli to create a table on the instance.

```
 export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=test
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=test
export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=test

aws dynamodb create-table \
   --table-name $tableName \
   --region local-env \
   --attribute-definitions AttributeName=id,AttributeType=S AttributeName=type,AttributeType=S \
   --key-schema AttributeName=id,KeyType=HASH AttributeName=type,KeyType=RANGE \
   --billing-mode PAY_PER_REQUEST \
   --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

The table is created and works perfect. And I can use below command to list the table:

```
$ AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=test aws dynamodb list-tables --region local-env --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
{
    "TableNames": [
        "test"
    ]
}
```

However, if I change the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` to some value other than `test`, it gives me an empty table list. That makes me think this instance is using `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` as a namespace to separate tables. My question is how I can list all `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` on this instance?